# table does not appear when using the package formattable() in R 4.1.0 or R 4.0.3 version

Tags: r, formattable

I'm trying to use formatable() but I'm not successful. I'm using some examples from the official CRAN documentation, but not even the examples are running.

i try version R 4.1.0 and 4.0.3, but dont worked.

my code exemple:

```
library(formattable)
formattable(mtcars, list(mpg = color_bar("lightgray", proportion)))
```

when using the command the column information disappears
[image]

Update:

SessionInfo()

```
R version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8.1 x64 (build 9600)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252  LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_1.0.2       readxl_1.3.1      writexl_1.3.1     webshot_0.5.2    
[5] htmltools_0.4.0   formattable_0.2.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.4.6      cellranger_1.1.0  pillar_1.4.6      compiler_4.0.5   
 [5] dbplyr_1.4.4      tools_4.0.5       digest_0.6.25     jsonlite_1.6.1   
 [9] evaluate_0.14     lubridate_1.7.9   lifecycle_0.2.0   tibble_3.0.1     
[13] gtable_0.3.0      lattice_0.20-41   pkgconfig_2.0.3   rlang_0.4.7      
[17] DBI_1.1.0         cli_2.0.2         rstudioapi_0.11   yaml_2.2.1       
[21] xfun_0.14         terra_1.2-10      raster_3.4-5      knitr_1.28       
[25] generics_0.0.2    vctrs_0.3.4       htmlwidgets_1.5.1 grid_4.0.5       
[29] tidyselect_1.1.0  glue_1.4.1        R6_2.4.1          fansi_0.4.1      
[33] rmarkdown_2.2     sp_1.4-2          purrr_0.3.4       ggplot2_3.3.2    
[37] blob_1.2.1        magrittr_1.5      scales_1.1.1      codetools_0.2-18 
[41] ellipsis_0.3.1    assertthat_0.2.1  colorspace_1.4-1  munsell_0.5.0    
[45] crayon_1.3.4
```

`formattable_0.2.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you provide `sessionInfo()`, please? I tried to run the code, and it works fine for me.

This is my `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Pop!_OS 20.04 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.9.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.9.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_DK.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_DK.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_DK.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_DK.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] formattable_0.2.1 forcats_0.5.1     stringr_1.4.0     dplyr_1.0.6       purrr_0.3.4       readr_1.4.0       tidyr_1.1.3      
 [8] tibble_3.1.2      ggplot2_3.3.3     tidyverse_1.3.1  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tidyselect_1.1.1  xfun_0.23         bslib_0.2.4       haven_2.4.1       colorspace_2.0-1  vctrs_0.3.8       generics_0.1.0   
 [8] htmltools_0.5.1.1 yaml_2.2.1        utf8_1.2.1        rlang_0.4.11      jquerylib_0.1.4   pillar_1.6.1      glue_1.4.2       
[15] withr_2.4.2       DBI_1.1.1         dbplyr_2.1.1      modelr_0.1.8      readxl_1.3.1      lifecycle_1.0.0   munsell_0.5.0    
[22] gtable_0.3.0      cellranger_1.1.0  rvest_1.0.0       htmlwidgets_1.5.3 evaluate_0.14     knitr_1.33        fansi_0.4.2      
[29] broom_0.7.6       Rcpp_1.0.6        scales_1.1.1      backports_1.2.1   jsonlite_1.7.2    fs_1.5.0          hms_1.1.0        
[36] digest_0.6.27     stringi_1.6.2     grid_4.1.0        cli_2.5.0         tools_4.1.0       sass_0.3.1        magrittr_2.0.1   
[43] crayon_1.4.1      pkgconfig_2.0.3   ellipsis_0.3.2    xml2_1.3.2        reprex_2.0.0      lubridate_1.7.10  assertthat_0.2.1 
[50] rmarkdown_2.8     httr_1.4.2        rstudioapi_0.13   R6_2.5.0          compiler_4.1.0
```

What version of `formattable_0.2.1` and `R Studio` are you using?

[image]

**Edit 1:** It appears that the font is white. Can you try to edit the color of `cyl`, and see what happens?

```
formattable(mtcars, list(mpg = color_bar("lightgray", proportion), cyl = color_text("blue", "blue")))
```

**Edit 2:** You are using an outdated `R Studio` version, however, the problem is related to the themes. If you are using custom themes, make sure that these does not set the font in the viewer pane as white.

Comment: Hi, I did `sessinfo()`. My formattable is `formattable_0.2.1`

Comment: Ok, I think I see the issue now. Your font is white! :-) Did you edit your viewer settings?

Comment: Try to change the color of `cyl`, to verify this.

Comment: hello @Serkan, now got it, the problem. the problem is the visualization and not necessarily the package. I think to get around the problem I should export the whole `markdown` to pdf by the `knit` command

Comment: This was my point, yes. However, you can fix this, I guess, by changing your R Studio Theme. Try Options > Appearance > Editor Theme > xcode! (As an example)

Tell me how it went, and Ill modify my answer accordingly.

Comment: Hello @Serkan,  I changed the theme to `xcode!` and it worked!!!! Now everything has appeared

Comment: You find this under `Tools`, and clicking `Global Options`. However, the latest version of `R-Studio` is 1.4 - so please update accordingly.

Comment: Good! :-) It should work with all themes though, unless it is custom themes. Accept the answer, so we know it is answered! :-)